# install GD library in ubuntu Unmet dependancies

Tags: php, ubuntu

Hi guys  I am trying to insall php GD library by using  **sudo apt-get install php5-gd** command. But it says unmet dependencies. Here is the output.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
php5-gd : Depends: php5-common (= 5.4.6-1ubuntu1) but 5.4.6-1ubuntu1.2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Any help??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your repositories

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list
```

if you have no different versions, try to update packages list:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and than try to install php5-gd

Comment: I think, you have non standard repositories. There is no ubuntu1.2 php in official mirror. Try to get `php5-gd` package from `https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-security/+archive/ppa/+build/4361053` and install with `sudo dpkg -i php5-gd...deb`

Comment: I am not good in ubuntu. Can you tell me how to install package from launchpad. I mean can you give me the command line instruction.

Comment: just download it from the link i post and use command: `sudo dpkg -i /path/to/debfile.deb`

Answer (score 0):

Check if it exist in /etc/apt/preferences.d/php5_3 file ...

I've added the following:

```
Package: php5-gd
Pin: release a=precise
Pin-Priority: 991
```

After that:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install php5-gd
```

Check with:

```
php -m |grep gd
```

Restart your apache.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use aptitude command instead of apt-get, which deals with dependencies better than apt-get:
`sudo aptitude install php5-gd`
It should help you downgrade the bothering package.

(Answer from maverickaddicted on http://ubuntuforums.org)